# Ejecucion de jobs de manera manual Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jobs, integración-continua

Estoy iniciando con jenkins y quisiera consultarles si existe alguna manera de ejecutar los jobs de manera manual u otra forma, (entiendo que es absurdo pero me pasa lo siguiente) ya que estoy haciendo pruebas de configuración tengo seleccionada la opción de que se ejecuten las pruebas cuando hago un push en mi repositorio de git, que es lo que se requiere cuando el proyecto esté en producción, pero como ahora estoy haciendo pruebas mas que nada en la configuración del jenkins (cambio de algunas versiones de algunos complementos, jdk por ejemplo ya que el proyecto está en java y cosas así) para poder ejecutar los jobs básicamente le tengo que agregar un espacio a mi jenkisfile para que haga un cambio y luego hacer un push, entonces he aquí mi consulta, es posible hacer esto de otra manera? sin tener que tocar mi código fuente e iniciar los jobs? solo sería temporal en el tiempo que haga pruebas, y como voy a estar haciendo esto en varios proyectos me ayudaría un montón

Quedo atenta a su conocimiento, muchas gracias de antemano

Comment: Cada job tiene una opción de _build_ o _build with parameters_. Ahí lo lanzas manual.